# IE does not reflect the changes in css on input:valid without moving mouse over the element

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, internet-explorer, angularjs-directive

I have a label in a text-box, and the label appears only when there is some valid text in the text box. The code is working fine, and this comes into effect in chrome and mozilla too. Only in IE, it works after the mouse is moved over the input control, or if the mouse is already on the input control, it works only when mouse is moved away from the input control.

I have given the CSS below, which should actually come into effect without any movement of mouse, but when some text is entered in the text box.

```css
.float-label input:valid + label {
  font-size: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  content: " ";
  -webkit-opacity: 1;
  -moz-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=(100));
  filter: alpha(opacity=(100));
  z-index: 3;
  top: -1px;
  color: #60798d;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group float-label float-label-dark">
  <input type="text" class="login-form-control login-form-control-dark" placeholder="Username" required>
  <label>Username</label>
</div>
```

I would be happy to fix this from the CSS side itself, any suggestions please !

EDIT - I do not know why this is considered off topic. The code clearly indicates the issue.
Anyway, now I am thinking of depending on angular, and I need to achieve completely from directive( without using any code in controller), I am trying to toggle a class when text is entered/removed in text box.

```
 (function () {
          angular.module("app.floatLabel",[]).directive("floatLabel", floatLabel);
     function floatLabel() {
    return {      
      restrict: "C",
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
       var childInput = element.children(":input");

        scope.$watch(function(){
           var childInput = element.children(":input");
           return childInput.val().length;
         },
          function(nv,ov)
         {
          console.log("nv = "+nv+" ov= "+ov);
       });

     }
   }
  }
 }
 )();
```

However, this is not logging to console when the number of characters change in the text box. Please help me in writing this directive in a right way.

Comment: I am checking this in IE-10.

Comment: We'd need the HTML as well. What makes the input actually valid?

Comment: Also, what is the `content` property doing in there?

Comment: The pseudo classes `:valid` & `:invalid` are only supported for IE10+ according to [this](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/v/valid/)

Comment: So what can I use to check whether there is something entered in the text box, and change CSS accordingly. 
PS: It works in IE-10, only problem is you need to move the mouse over

Comment: Although the code does not reflect my actual use-case, the issue can be reproduced by running the above code-snippet, in chrome you can see change happening to the label when you enter the text in text-box, but in IE(IE 10 is what I am using) , it occurs only after mouse movement

Comment: Well as both IE8 and 9 has a higher usage statistics than 10 and neither support this, you might want to decide if script can be a choice